# except home page , all the links throwing an error "404 Pages Cannot be found"

Tags: 404-error

automatically some of the pages was throwing an error "404 Page cannot be found".
sending you the link of my site, were i am getting an error " http://kvorg.satvix.com/downloads-publications-test/ "// throwing an error
"http://kvorg.satvix.com/" // this page is displaying 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens after migrating to a new environment. Try just resaving your permalink settings here http://kvorg.satvix.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php by just clicking save changes.